# What is wrong with this BMI calculator?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double lbs;
  double kg = lbs/2.205;
  double feet;
  double inches; 
  double height= ((feet * 12) + (inches))/39.37;
  double bmi=(kg)/(height * height);


  cout << "What is your weight (lbs)?" << endl;
  cin >> lbs;
  cout << "What is your height ? (feet only)" << endl;
  cin >> feet;
  cout << "What is your height ? (inches)" << endl;
  cin >> inches;
  cout << "Your BMI is : " << kg/(height*height);

}
```

The final output is: inf. What does that mean?

Comment: When you do `double kg = lbs/2.205;`, what is the value in `kg`?  Voting to close as a typo.  You need to do your calculations **after** you get the input.

Comment: You are doing your calculations *before* you read input from the user...

Comment: `double kg = lbs/2.205;` this is undefined behavior `lbs` is not initialized.

Comment: While `double kg = lbs/2.205;` looks like a formula that defines a relation between `kg` and `lbs`, it isn't.

Comment: The big takeaway here is that a c++ statement is not  a mathematical relationship that gets reevaluated each time the variable is used. Instead `c++` statements are calculated at the time when the execution reaches that code line.

Comment: If you want to establish the mathematical relationship that way, you can use a lambda, e.g., `auto kg = [&]{ return lbs/2.205; };` and then invoke it using `kg()`.  Same with `height` and `bmi`.

Comment: `inf` means infinity

Answer (score 2):

Consider this sequence of statements:

```
double lbs;
double kg = lbs/2.205;  // lbs is uninitialized here, oops
cout << "What is your weight (lbs)?" << endl;
cin >> lbs;
```

You are using `lbs` before reading it from the user, and in fact, before initializing it at all, which invokes undefined behavior.

You need to reorder the statements like this:

```
double lbs;
cout << "What is your weight (lbs)?" << endl;
cin >> lbs;
double kg = lbs/2.205;  // compute kg after reading in lbs
```

You need to do a similar thing for the other variables as well.

Comment: thanks for the help dude

Comment: @TylerKay No problem :) Consider accepting the answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Calculation must be done **after** reading values. Otherwise, indeterminate values are used to calculation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double lbs;
  double feet;
  double inches;
  // remove this because this is not used
  //double bmi=(kg)/(height * height);


  cout << "What is your weight (lbs)?" << endl;
  cin >> lbs;
  cout << "What is your height ? (feet only)" << endl;
  cin >> feet;
  cout << "What is your height ? (inches)" << endl;
  cin >> inches;
  double kg = lbs/2.205; // move this
  double height= ((feet * 12) + (inches))/39.37; // move this
  cout << "Your BMI is : " << kg/(height*height);

}
```

Comment: thanks dude, appreciate it!